# Databricks load file from path which contains equals (=) sign

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks, azure-log-analytics

I'm looking to export Azure Monitor data from Log Analytics to a storage account and the read the JSON files into Databricks using PySpark.

The blob path for the Log Analytics export contains an equals (=) sign and Databricks throws and exception when using the path.

```
WorkspaceResourceId=/subscriptions/subscription-id/resourcegroups/<resource-group>/providers/microsoft.operationalinsights/workspaces/<workspace>/y=<four-digit numeric year>/m=<two-digit numeric month>/d=<two-digit numeric day>/h=<two-digit 24-hour clock hour>/m=<two-digit 60-minute clock minute>/PT05M.json
```

[Log Analytics Data Export](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/logs-data-export?tabs=portal#storage-account)

Is there a way to escape the equals sign so that the JSON files can be loaded from the blob location?

Comment: I have no problems reading paths containing `=` on dbfs backed by azure blob storage(reading with`spark.read.format("json").load(path)`). Could you elaborate on how you are reading in the data and post the exception that you receive.

Comment: Strange. I even get an error when using dbutils.fs.ls(). Are you using blob storage or ADLS with hierarchical namespace?

Comment: I'm using ADLS with hierarchical namespace enabled.

Comment: Must be the blob endpoint. Will try it with ADLS HNS.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the similar use case referring from Microsoft Documentation, below are the steps:

1. Mount the storage container. We can do it with python code as below, make sure you pass all the parameters correct, because incorrect parameters will lead to multiple different errors.

   ```
    dbutils.fs.mount(
          source = "wasbs://<container-name>@<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net",
          mount_point = "/mnt/<mount-name>",
          extra_configs = {"<conf-key>":dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "<scope-name>", key = "<key-name>")})
   ```

   Below are the parameters description:

   - `<storage-account-name>`  is the name of your Azure Blob storage account.
   - `<container-name>`  is the name of a container in your Azure Blob storage account.
   - `<mount-name>`  is a DBFS path representing where the Blob storage container or a folder inside the container (specified in  `source`) will be mounted in DBFS.
   - `<conf-key>`  can be either  `fs.azure.account.key.<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net`  or  `fs.azure.sas.<container-name>.<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net`
   - `dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "<scope-name>", key = "<key-name>")`  gets the key that has been stored as a  [secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/secrets/secrets)  in a  [secret scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/secrets/secret-scopes).
2. Then you can access those files as below:

   ```
    df = spark.read.text("/mnt/<mount-name>/...")
    df = spark.read.text("dbfs:/<mount-name>/...")
   ```

Also there are multiple ways in accessing the file, all of these were mentioned clearly in the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/azure-storage).

And check this Log Analytics workspace [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/logs-data-export?tabs=rest) to understand about exporting the data to Azure Storage.

Comment: the problem is that Microsoft uses the same name `m` for both months & minutes. As result, when you read with partitions inference, then Spark job fails because of the duplicate columns